# error in query to get balance

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have a Cash table with fields: doc_num,narration,date,creditor,debtor
now i want to show sum(creditor-debtor) as balance for each rows.also show previous balance
like this :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
doc_num-------date----------narration------------credit-------debtor---balance
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                         previous balance                                 2000    
 1       2014/06/10        remit             5000          0              5000
 2       2014/06/12        bar                  0          2000           3000
 3       2014/06/15        remit             1000          0              4000
```

this is my query :

```
SELECT  ''                  AS docnum,
        ''                  AS c_date,
        'previous balance'  AS narration,
        " "                 AS creditor,
        " "                 AS debtor,
        Sum(creditor-debtor),
        "c_date< ' " &  2014/06/10  & "'" AS Balance 
FROM    Cash 
UNION 
SELECT  doc_num,
        c_date,
        narration,
        creditor,
        debtor,
        Sum(creditor-debtor),
        "doc_num<=" & doc_num AS Balance 
FROM    Cash
WHERE   (((Cash.c_date) Between ("2014/06/10") And ("2014/06/15")))
ORDER BY docnum;
```

i faced this err:
you tried to execute query that dose not include the specified expression 'doc_num' as part of an aggregate
i use this query in access(mdb)
what's a correct query?
thanks

Comment: You're missing `group by` statements after the where clause listing all the non-aggregated columns.

Comment: it's ms access... as the error says :)

Comment: you are using SUM, therefore you need to use group by

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:  the '' and " " are throwing me off a bit.

```
SELECT  ''                  AS docnum,
        ''                  AS c_date,
        'previous balance'  AS narration,
        " "                 AS creditor,
        " "                 AS debtor,
        Sum(creditor-debtor),
        "c_date< ' " &  2014/06/10  & "'" AS Balance 
FROM    Cash 
Group by '','','previous balance', " ", " ", "c_date< ' " &  2014/06/10  & "'"
UNION 
SELECT  doc_num,
        c_date,
        narration,
        creditor,
        debtor,
        Sum(creditor-debtor),
        "doc_num<=" & doc_num AS Balance 
FROM    Cash
WHERE   (((Cash.c_date) Between ("2014/06/10") And ("2014/06/15")))
GROUP BY doc_num,
        c_date,
        narration,
        creditor,
        debtor,
        "doc_num<=" & doc_num 
ORDER BY docnum;
```

Comment: thank's for y code . i use this code in ms access an dose not work again.do you run this code ?

Comment: No as I don't have tables and database you have.  I would suggest breaking down the code into the two separate select statements and trying each individually that way you can focus on one statement at a time for resolution.  I Know the root of your problem is with the group by; but I'm not positive of the syntax given how these are setup.

Comment: ok,to according my table can you write query to get balance from credit and debtor in each rows ? it's vital for me .